# Is selenite (hydrous calcium sulfate) dangerous when you grind it up?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, biochemistry, minerals

I was wondering about the safety of a specific mineral, Selenite. From my research, I have read that selenite is the crystalline form of gypsum, which is hydrous calcium sulfate. I was wondering if I were to grind selenite and mix about a 1/2 tsp with 3 ounces of water and spray around my home, is that dangerous? Also will the grinding process be dangerous if any small amounts of dust are inhaled?

Comment: You should check its msds:https://beta-static.fishersci.com/content/dam/fishersci/en_US/documents/programs/education/regulatory-documents/sds/chemicals/chemicals-c/S25230.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Gypsum is the major constituent of plaster. It is non-toxic.

Our lungs are capable of filtering out particles greater than 50 micrometers in diameter. Any dust finer than that is potentially dangerous.